# Tesseract run time error

Tags: java

I wrote the following code.

```
public class TesseractExample {

static
{
    System.load("F:/Tess4J-1.3-src/Tess4J/lib/win32-x86-64/liblept168.dll");
    System.load("F:/Tess4J-1.3-src/Tess4J/lib/win32-x86-64/libtesseract302.dll");

     public static void main(String[] args) {
             File imageFile = new File("12.png");
             Tesseract1 instance = new Tesseract1(); // JNA Direct Mapping

    try {
        String result = instance.doOCR(imageFile);
        System.out.println(result);
    } catch (TesseractException e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
}
```

When I run this code, I get following error

```
SEVERE: Input not set!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Input not set!
    at com.sun.media.imageioimpl.plugins.tiff.TIFFImageReader.getNumImages(TIFFImageReader.java:268)
    at net.sourceforge.vietocr.ImageIOHelper.getIIOImageList(Unknown Source)
    at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract1.doOCR(Unknown Source)
    at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract1.doOCR(Unknown Source)
    at TesseractExample.main(TesseractExample.java:28)


java.lang.IllegalStateException: Input not set!
```

Please help me.

Comment: Can you indicate the line number in the code please?

Comment: The error has occurred for the following statement                         "String result = instance.doOCR(imageFile)

Comment: Any Updates on this ?? I am getting the exact same error.

Answer (score 0):

Just for other's reference "Input not set!" means you have not set the input image file. It's most likely that the file does not exist at the specified location. Substituting with a full path will help you debug the issue better.